# Angular 2 reactive form validate pattern for number with two decimal places

Tags: regex, validation, angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to validate an input on an angular 2 reactive form so that only numbers with two decimal places are valid.

I am using the `Validators.pattern('^\d+\.\d{2}$')` method to match against a regex pattern.  According to https://regex101.com/r/1DbMZq/1 my regex matches correctly but when I use it in my form it is always invalid.

Here is a plunker illustrating the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/TpBZtgNNww4CnTwQFtef?p=preview

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `Validators.pattern('^\\d+\\.\\d{2}$')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep, that seems to have done it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I assume you have to pass `Regexp` type instead of `string` like:

```
Validators.pattern(/^\d+\.\d{2}$/)
```

Here's updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qIYaxM35USPM3cAvrms7?p=preview)

If you use string as parameter of the `pattern` method then your Regexp will be changed as shown below

[image]

Comment: You should add that `'\\d+\\.\\d{2}'` is also a possibility.